# WPF: HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsPanel

Tags: wpf, styles, datatemplate, itemscontrol, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a ``TreeView`which uses a custom`ItemsPanel`to show the first level of items in a`StackPanel`, but I need to show subitems in a`StackPanel`too. The problem is, the second level of items are shown in a`WrapPanel`, and as`HierarchicalDataTemplate`doesn't have an`ItemsPanel` property I'm not sure how to do this. This is my xaml:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treGlobalCards">
    <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="{Binding Orientation,RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.TemplatedParent}}"
                        MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="CardTypeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CardType}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new DataTemplate that uses a StackPanel and set the HierachicalDataTemplate's "ItemTemplate" to that new DataTemplate.

i.e.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="someTemp">
    <StackPanel />
</DataTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="hierTemp" ItemSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource someTemp}" />
```